# Java: byte cast issue

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
byte b=10;
System.out.println("Test b:"+b);
```

This codes is compiled and works without problems. However, I cant understand why. 10 is literal here and it is integer literal (default for integer). So we have here casting as on the left side we have byte and on the right side we have integer. And this is narrowing as `byte<integer`. As I understand narrowing must always be explicit casting otherwise the code won't compile. Could anyone explain why this code works?

Comment: `long x = 1;` this compiles too. but `int x = 100000000000000;` wont

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12419618/1343161) is a nice explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works, because `10` is a compile-time constant. The compiler can *infer* that it fits the `byte` range, so it allows the assignment.

You can a play a bit with assigning values to a `byte` variable. If you for example do

```
 byte b = 128;
```

then you'll get a compilation error, because `128` doesn't fit the `byte` range. In this case you can do a cast:

```
 byte b = (byte) 128;
```

but then you'll end up with an overflow and `b` will be evaluated to `-128`.

Comment: Then could you explain why float f=23.22 not work? 23.22 also fits float range...

Comment: The floating point values are something else - checkout the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

`byte`'s max value is `127`.

`10` fits in the byte so it is a valid assignment.

try

```
byte b = 140; //it wont
```