# Why does 2//0.2 return 9.0 but 5//0.5 return 10.0 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, division, pythoninterpreter

In Python 3 interpreter,

```
1//0.1
2//0.2
4//0.4
```

returns 9.0, but

```
5//0.5
3//0.3
```

returns 10.0. Is this rounding-off behavior correct?

[image]

Comment: `//` is floor division. The floating point result of `1/0.1` is probably like `9.999...` which truncates down to `9` after you floor the result, which is what `//` does.

Comment: @alkasm  Not really. Check yourself with `f"{1/.1:.64f}"`

Comment: @wim wait wtf, what's going on here then? I'm confused, since 0.1 is definitely over 0.1 in floating point format.

Comment: This has a better explanation: [rounding errors in Python floor division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38588815/674039)