# What is the value of 5.5//1.1 in python? and How?

Tags: python, floor-division

What's the step by step answer for 5.5//1.1.
While running in compiler it gives **4.0** as an answer.

Comment: Java actually gives 5.0 as the answer. I checked in python, it gives same as what you got!

Comment: Which platform, CPU architecture and Python runtime? (That said, in general, this comes down to "IEEE floating point is unintuitive to people accustomed to thinking in decimal", which isn't in any way specific to Python)

Comment: I tried ``` import math   <new line>    print(math.floor(5.5/1.1))```. This worked correctly and gave 5 as answer

Comment: @Ruthvik OP is concerned about `5.5 // 1.1`, not `5.5 / 1.1`

Comment: @BatWannaBe, I know, but to get the correct answer, i gave this solution

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588815/rounding-errors-in-python-floor-division)

Comment: That's because there is no 5.5 or 1.1 in python (floating-point finite representation) it's actually a float like 5.500000000000001  and 1.100000000000001  which makes the floor of the division of to be 4.0. `5.500000000000001//1.100000000000001=4.0`

Comment: For the record, 5.5 can be accurately represented as a float (it's ``17/2``) but 1.1 cannot (it's ``11/(5*2)``) – its float representation is slightly *larger* than 1.1. Check for example ``f"{1.1:.16f}"``.