# What is an example of approximate value in case of float data type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Decimal stores the exact value, where as flat stores an approximation.

Quote from an MSDN article:

> Approximate numeric data types do not store the exact values specified
> for many numbers; they store an extremely close approximation of the
> value

What is the example of value where an approximate value will be stored? For example say I store 100.15; when I retrieve I get the same value back. What is an example of value to show the approximation?

Comment: It starts coming into play in values with very large precision.  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server

Comment: Also probably relevant: [How are floating point numbers stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644699/how-are-floating-point-numbers-stored-in-memory)

Comment: Suggest you read this [floating point guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/). And it is easy to get confused since an application might have rules for displaying floating point values that are not obvious.

Comment: Try `DECLARE @f FLOAT = 100.15; SELECT FORMAT(@f, 'G17')`.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the example of value where an approximate value will be
> stored? For example say I store 100.15; when I retrieve I get the same
> value back. What is an example of value to show the approximation?

100.15 is a decimal value that cannot be stored exactly with `float`.

What tool are you using to view the value? SSMS will round the result whereas SQLCMD will not.

```
sqlcmd -Q"SELECT CAST(100.15 as float);"
```

Result:

```
------------------------
      100.15000000000001
```

Comment: I might point out that many numbers in other bases cannot be stored in `decimal` so it's not really true to say that `decimal` is exact and `float` is not, just that `decimal` is exact for rational base-10 numbers up to the given precision, and `float` is exact for rational base-2 numbers up to the given precision