# When to use NaN or +/-Infinity?

Tags: c#, nan, infinity

What are the benefits of `NaN`, `PositiveInfinity` or `NegativeInfinity` for `float` and `double`? When should we use or avoid them?

If there are constants like these, why does `float.Parse("a")` throw an error rather than returning `float.NaN`?

How is `NaN` different than `null`? Why is `division by zero` even possible for floating types?

Comment: you could use TryParse rather than Parse?

Comment: Used because of math operations.

Comment: @Evgeny: vaguest comment ever.

Comment: @Liam my question wasn't about how to parse, I would like to know why there is NaN in a strongly typed environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does NaN mean for doubles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112529/what-does-nan-mean-for-doubles)

Comment: Also, Parse failing does not necessarily mean that the value is Not a Number. For example, it will fail with Unicode digits http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm `.Parse("１")` or with some different culture settings

Answer (score 12):

Infinities are used because they are part of the arithmetic system supported by floating point. There are various operations, such as dividing by zero, in which infinity is a useful result and is mathematically sensible. Obviously, no direct physical quantity can be infinite (you cannot have infinitely many grams, for example), but infinity may be a useful value for some aspect of a mathematical model of physical processes or other things that humans model with computers.

NaNs are used because the arithmetic system is incomplete. That is, there are operations with input values for which the proper mathematical result is not representable within floating point. For example, sqrt(-1) is a legitimate mathematical operation, but the result, the imaginary number *i*, is not representable in floating point. So NaN is used as a placeholder to indicate that the values have gone outside the floating point numbers. NaN can also be used for other purposes, such as marking data that is not otherwise initialized, to help with debugging.

`float.Parse("a")` throws an error rather than returning a NaN because it is a not a legitimate operation. This expression does not perform a mathematical operation that has a proper result outside the representable numbers. It is an actual error, so it throws an error.

Comment: I like this answer; it explains why Parse fails, as you basically are trying to unify two types that have no relationship (float and string)

Answer (score 9):

They are not so much something you *use* as they are something you need to be aware of:

```
double hmm = 1.0 / 0.0;
double hmm2 = -1.0 / 0.0;
double hmm3 = 0.0 / 0.0;
Console.WriteLine("1/0 == {0}", hmm);
Console.WriteLine("-1/0 == {0}", hmm2);
Console.WriteLine("0/0 == {0}", hmm3);
```

Output:

```
1/0 == Infinity
-1/0 == -Infinity
0/0 == NaN
```

EDIT:
As for this question:

> If there are constants like these, why does float.Parse("a") throw an error rather than returning float.NaN?

`double.NaN` is actually a mathematical definition in a way - it is "defined" as `0.0/0.0` - while the words "not a number" imply that something like `double.Parse("a")` should also return `double.NaN`, it does not. Why?

My hunch is because it would be impossible to determine if the `double.NaN` you received was the result of garbage data (in the case of the string) or the *actual* definition of an indeterminate number, like zero divided by zero. So, to make a distinction between these two cases, `double.Parse("a")` throws an `Exception`, which I feel is more accurate.

Comment: Why division by zero is possible for floating types?

Comment: @LZW Simple answer: because you can type/compile/run `1.0/0.0` - in olden days, this would cause a `DivideByZeroException`, but there are theoretical applications for "defined" `Infinity` and `NaN` values - for example, WPF uses both of these to signify "unset" or "undefined" sizes, etc.

Comment: @LZW: In many cases, determining *whether* a floating-point expression could be evaluated without any intermediate computations going out of range would require computations that are more expensive than those necessary to evaluate the expression when everything is in range.  Allowing code to try to evaluate the expression and then find out if there was a problem is thus cheaper than requiring code to detect problematic conditions in advance.

Answer (score 6):

> If there are constants like these why `float.Parse("a")` throw error rather than returning `float.NaN`?

Because neither of the alternatives you listed are applicable here:

`PositiveInfinity` and `NegativeInfinity` are just that – i.e. they are the result of expressions such as `1/0` or `-1/0`.

`NaN` is the result of `0/0` – that is, an expression whose result is not (normally) well-defined and doesn’t result in a number.

`float.Parse("a")` is nothing like that. Admittedly, it could potentially be represented by `NaN` but then you couldn’t distinguish between the user entering an invalid `float` value (`a`) and a valid `float` value (`NaN`). This is not a very strong argument, however: `NaN` is *explicitly* a placeholder for an invalid number so it could conceivably be used to represent invalid user input.

On the other hand, there are other types which have a `Parse` method and for which no `NaN` value exists (such as `int`). For these types, `Parse` *must* therefore signal an error. It would be inconsistent (and therefore bad API design) to make different types’ `Parse` method behave differently.

Comment: JavaScript's parseFloat("a") returns NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the results from arithmetic, the infinity values can be used to define no limits for a context.

For example: A Parent WPF Control asking one of its children to measure itself, under the context that there is no size restriction; i.e. availableSize is PositiveInfinity

Ref: [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx)

Comment: This is the only answer giving real world (not theoretical) example.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve NAN and infinity, use this:

```
if (Double.IsNaN(YourValue) || Double.IsInfinity(YourValue))
{
   YourValue = 0;
}
```