# How use google map api to find out a position is in radius

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3

This is my method:

```
public bool IsPositionInRadious(double centerLatitude, double centerLongitude, int radiosInMeter, double positionLatitude, double positionLongitude)
{
    string apiUrl = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/.....";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    return TranslateResponse(response);
}
```

As you see I want to use google map API to find that is my position is in the circle with specific center and radius. Does any one have any idea? Which API let me find out?

Comment: Search for the Haversine distance formulae, thats what you need (No need to use google maps at all)

Comment: @Gusman Thank you, I find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684281/calculating-distance-between-two-points-in-c-sharp#answer-22684452