# Issue with variable type

Tags: java, floating-point, formatting, biginteger, bigdecimal

I am basically totalling a number which becomes very large. I am using float as I wanted to retain the level of precision, but it only goes up to 100k. Here is some sample output.

```
 x 361 y 800 width 530 h 800 intensity 93581.52477873862
 x 362 y 800 width 530 h 800 intensity 93829.5759344697
 x 363 y 800 width 530 h 800 intensity 94079.55780857801
 x 364 y 800 width 530 h 800 intensity NaN
 x 365 y 800 width 530 h 800 intensity NaN
 x 366 y 800 width 530 h 800 intensity NaN
```

I have tried double etc. and had no luck! Anyone have any ideas on what is best to use?

Thanks

Comment: Floats can go much higher than this, so something else is wrong. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean) for some info on the meaning of NaN. Is your code dividing inadvertently zero by zero or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Try [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). It keeps the precision (e.g. number of fraction digits) you want.

Comment: I absolutely agree with icza's suggestion. If you are doing anything even remotely serious with decimal arithmetic (especially currency), you should *always* use 'BigDecimal'. There are plenty of answers here on SO to tell you why that is.

Answer (score 2):

`float` can "go higher then 10k" and `double` is always the preferred choice. If the numbers get really big and you need all digits, then use `BigDecimal`.

If you can't get above 10k, then there's some "other" problem in your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Floats can go way higher than this - try for example:

```
    float x = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000.0f; 
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(x*x);
```

which outputs:

```
1.0E36
Infinity
```

So something else is wrong.  Note that using really big numbers results in `Infinity` not `NaN`.

Is your code dividing inadvertently zero by zero or something like that? What is the actual calculation you are performing?

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean) for some info on the meaning of NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a different problem than you think you are having.

Fact 1: float can get far larger than 10k.  Around 340000000000000000000000000000000000k.

Fact 2: float addition overflows result in Infinity, not NaN (Not a Number).

You have an error in your mathematics somewhere.  The calculation at x 364 is resulting in some arithmetic error that is messing up your sum.  The precision is not the problem.