# Checking for NaN and using it in an If

Tags: java, if-statement, nan

I am collecting some data from a database and adding them together to get some statistics, but since I backdate some of my data then the calculated sum will sometime come up as `NaN` (not a number) I want to create an if sentence that says if(not a number) then exclude this data from my table.

How do I test if the data (in this case double) is `NaN`?

Comment: Do you care about decimals also?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are static methods [`Float.isNaN(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#isNaN(float)) and [`Double.isNaN(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28double%29) that you can use.

```
double x = ... // whatever calculation you do

if (Double.isNaN(x)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `x` can be any numeric type or a wrapper of a Number and this will still work. i.e. it doesn't have to be `double`.

Comment: There is also Float.isNan(x)

Comment: There is also isNaN(x)

Comment: @SunnyRGupta Where is that at?

Comment:  - OOPS. I did it again. JavaScript mixed in here.
There is no isNaN directly. I take back my words.

Answer (score 4):

You can test for NaN two ways.  You can use the built in function

```
Double.isNaN(x)
```

or perform the check this does which is

```
if (x != x)
```

provided x is a `double` or a `float`

Comment: The second piece of code is only good if x is `double`. If for some reason the code uses `Double` then it will end up comparing reference.

Comment: How this works ? That x is double, but Not a Number ?

Comment: @Vash: NaN is very special, it is probably the only thing that when compare not equal to itself will return true.

Comment: For those who want to know more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean

Answer (score -6):

This would work for you.

```
if(number == Float.NaN)
```

Comment: This will always be false as NaN != NaN

Comment: // 1 method
if (Double.isNaN(doubleValue)) {
}
// 2.  method
if (doubleObject.isNan()) {
    ...
}
Simply doing:

if (var == Double.NaN) {
    ...
}