# Getting NaN when using get method

Tags: java, methods, get, nan

I'm making an BMI calculator for a diet programming I'm making for a piece of coursework. Originally I was making a a couple variables *public static* to get variables from another class. My BMI calculator worked fine this way.

I then figured out that I could use a *get method* (for more marks). So I changed by the previous variables to *private* and used a *get method*. But when I run this program I get NaN when the program prints out the the variable that holds the BMI, this never happened before!

Can anyone help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Weight {
private Scanner input;
private String readInput;
private String userWeightIsPounds;
private String userWeightIsStones;

private Scanner input2;
public static double userWeight;

public Weight(){
    userWeightIsPounds = ("Pounds");
    userWeightIsStones = ("Stones");        
}

public void findOutUserWeightMessage(){
    System.out.println("Firstly Do you weigh yourself in pounds or stones?");
}

public void findOutUserWeight(){
    input = new Scanner (System.in);
    readInput = input.nextLine();
    if(readInput.equals(userWeightIsPounds)){
        System.out.println("Ok then, enter your weight in pounds please.");
    }
    if(readInput.equals(userWeightIsStones)){
        System.out.println("Ok enter your weight in stones please.");
    }   

    input2 = new Scanner (System.in);
    userWeight = input2.nextFloat();
    if (userWeight > 20){
        System.out.println("You've enetered your weight as " + userWeight + " lbs. I'll save that information for later.");
    }else{
        userWeight = userWeight * 14;
        System.out.println("I've converted your weight into pounds for you. You weigh " + userWeight + " lbs. I'll save that information for later.");  
    }
}

public double static getUserWeight(){
    return userWeight;
}

}
```

And there is come code the the class that does the calculations. Ignore some of the println's I was trying to find out what was happening with my variables.

```
public class BMI {

private double userHeightSqaured;
private double bmiMutiplier;
private double weightDivideHeight;
private double userBmi;
private double userWeightBmi;
private double userHeightBmi;



BMI(){
    bmiMutiplier = 703;
    userWeightBmi = Weight.getUserWeight();
    userHeightBmi = Height.getUserHeight();
}

public void startUpBmiMessage(){
    System.out.print("Lets start with your BMI then shall we? ");
}

public void calculateUserBmi(){
    System.out.println("userWeightBmi is " + userWeightBmi);
    System.out.println("userWeightBmi is " + userHeightSqaured);

    userHeightSqaured = userHeightBmi * userHeightBmi;
    System.out.println("userHeightSqaured is " + userHeightSqaured);
    weightDivideHeight = userWeightBmi/userHeightSqaured;
    System.out.println("weightDivideHeight is " + weightDivideHeight);

    userBmi = weightDivideHeight * bmiMutiplier;
    System.out.println("weightDivideHeight is " + weightDivideHeight);
    System.out.println("bmiMutiplier is " + bmiMutiplier);


}   

public void calculateUserBmiMessage(){

    System.out.println("Your bmi is " + userBmi);

}
```

}

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean

Comment: Just a hint - the keyword `static` shouldn't appear anywhere in your code (except for the `main` method of course)

Comment: Thanks removed static. But eclipse keeps telling me that to change the modifier to static!

Comment: @JonathanCanning - Do you *understand* what `static` means???  What a `static` variable is?  What a `static` method is?  Why you can't access an instance variable from a static method?  Go back to your lecture notes / text book / whatever and read up on those topics.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to write a Java program that performs some calculations, and the result of your calculation is `NaN` - you can refer to the question [In Java, what does NaN mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean) for some info on `NaN`.

As for resolving your problem without seeing any code, and assuming your calculation worked fine with the same input before, it sounds like your switch from `public static` variables to private ones with getters has probably left some of your variables uninitialized, so their value defaults to 0 - Division by 0 is a common cause of `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the NaN is that this statement:

```
    weightDivideHeight = userWeightBmi/userHeightSqaured;
```

divided zero by zero.  In other words `userWeightBmi` and `userHeightSqaured` were both zero at that point.

The root problem seems to be that you haven't got your head around the difference between `static` and instance variables.  And when you should / should not use the two kinds of variable.