# What's the difference when using numeric literal in termination expression of a for statement?

Tags: java, for-loop, termination

Why does this piece of code:

```
String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter x"); //Input = 100
int x = Integer.parseInt(value);
double result = 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) //used variable "x" here
{
    result += (x * 1.0) / fact(i);
    x *= x;
}

public static int fact(int n) {
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

work differently from this one?

```
String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter x"); //Input = 100
int x = Integer.parseInt(value);   
double result = 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) //and here I used the value "100"
{
    result += (x * 1.0) / fact(i);
    x *= x;
}

public static int fact(int n) {
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

The only change that I made was using the value `100` instead of using the variable `x` in my termination expression!

When I run the first code, I get:

```
9.479341033333334E7
```

However, for the second one I always get

```
NaN
```

Why?

Comment: Well, because x changes mid-loop in the first one.

Comment: You might want to throw a comment in there to point at where the difference is. People whip through these questions, so it's in your interest to make your issue jump out at readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two snippets is this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
```

vs.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
```

In the first case, x gets much larger every time! Eventually, it will stop when `x` [overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001836/1768232) and becomes 0, which will be much sooner than in the second case. For an explanation as to why this results in 0 instead of some other random number, see: [Why does this multiplication integer overflow result in zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32042346/1768232)

In the second case, when `i = 34`, `fact(n)` will return 0, so the double division is `(0 * 1.0) /0` which results in `NaN`. Any double, when added to `NaN`, becomes `NaN`, which is why the second snippet results in `NaN`. See: [In Java, what does NaN mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean)

Comment: *x overflows and becomes 0* are you sure it will become 0 and not a negative?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, because I ran it. I'll be honest, I wasn't sure why.

Comment: Interesting, but knowing why it became 0 is outside of the quesiton. Good job done here.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I figured out why it results in 0, and [wrote it up here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32042346/1768232)