# Reaching zero after multiplying big integers in Java

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
int x= (int) Math.pow(2, 5);
for (int k=1; k <= 3; k++) {
    x *= (2*x);
}
System.out.println(x); // prints 0
```

It is simply initializing x to 32 and then multiplying it by its double every iteration of the loop. However, I expect the output the be a big number or at least an error, but **the final output is 0.** No, I tried to do some debugging by adding this:

```
int x= (int) Math.pow(2, 5);
for (int k=1; k <= 3; k++) {
    System.out.println(x + " * " + 2 * x);
    x *= (2*x);
}
System.out.println(x);
```

But the output is this:

```
32 * 64
2048 * 4096
8388608 * 16777216
0
```

Does anyone have any idea why the number suddenly becomes 0?

Comment: The numbers are too large, you need to use the BigInteger java import. This should help introduce you to how to use the import: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/

Comment: try debugging by printing `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x).length());` and you see that the next in the series is `32`

Comment: You have an overflow that causes the result of the multiplication operation to give a wrong value.

As `Integer` are coded on 32bits in Java the maximum value that can be assigned to a `int` variable before reaching an overflow is defined by `Integer.MAX_VALUE;//2147483647`. 

As work-around you can use `BigInteger` to do calculation over this limit (see Tim solution)
If you want to understand why the result is `0` and not `-1234578` or another number have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042346/why-does-this-multiplication-integer-overflow-result-in-zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 in binary is `100000`, a power of 2. Your "update procedure" `x = 2 * x * x;` maintains this property -- `x` is always a (bigger) power of 2. At the last iteration, you're seeing `x` overflow, since the `int` datatype only stores 32 bits, and the binary representation of `x` has more than 32 bits. The value printed is exactly `0` because the lowest 32 bits of `x` are all `0` (since `x` is a very large power of 2), and the `int` with 32 `0`'s is `0`.

Comment: So when I reach a value greater than 32 bits, Java automatically defaults to a 32 bit integer made of 0's?

Comment: When you need more than 32 bits to store an integer, Java's `int` type stores the "lowest" (least-significant) 32 bits. In your case, all of the lowest 32 bits happen to be `0`'s because your number is a large power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You are just looking at standard primitive integer overflow, which have a max value of `2,147,483,647`.  Java has a class `BigInteger` which has a much larger range (no theoretical limit) which you may use:

```
BigInteger x= new BigInteger(String.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2, 5)));
for (int k=1; k <= 3; k++) {
    System.out.println(x + " * " + x.multiply(new BigInteger("2")));
    BigInteger twice = x.multiply(new BigInteger("2"));
    x = x.multiply(twice);
}
System.out.println(x);

32 * 64
2048 * 4096
8388608 * 16777216
140737488355328
```

### Demo