# Quadratic programming - specific output

Tags: java, quadratic-programming

I want that the Quadratic program will print only the necessary output.
this is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]); 
    double b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]); 
    double c = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
    double temp, first, second;
    temp = (b*b - (4 * a * c));
    first = ((-1 * b) + Math.sqrt(temp)) / (2 * a);
    second = ((-1 * b) - Math.sqrt(temp)) / (2 * a);
    if (temp > 0)
        System.out.println (first);
    if (temp == 0)
      if (first == second)
          System.out.println (first);
      else
        System.out.println (first);
        System.out.println (second);
    if (temp < 0)
        System.out.println ("There are no solutions.");
}
```

When I'm writing: java Quadratic 1 0 1
it brings back: "NaN
There are no solutions."
**What is the NaN?**

and when I'm writing:  java Quadratic 1 -2 1
it prints twice:
"1.0
1.0". **How do I turn in into one?** because i've already wrote this if command:
if (first == second).

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp = (b*b - (4 * a * c));
```

when b = 0, this becomes:

```
temp = -(4 * a * c);
```

which when a and c are positive results in temp being negative, and you can't take the square root of a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

The NaN question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean) and in the various links in the comments and answers to that question.

The multiple outputs is probably because of the very last `else`. Even though you've indented the code such that it looks like the two `println`s are only executed if `temp == 0` and `first != second`, they aren't, only the first `println` is in the `else`, the second will get executed every time. Instead used:

```
else {
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much! It did work but there's still a problem when there are 2 answers. For example, for "java Quadratic 1 1 -2" - It prints only "1.0", even thought it should print 1.0 and -2.0.

Comment: @Dana In that case `temp` is 9 (1 * 1 - (4 * 1 * -2) = 1 - -8 = 9), so it's going into the `if (temp > 0)` and printing `first`.

Comment: I fixed it! Thank you :)