# Android app Returning NaN

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, nan

Why does calcGPA keep saying it equals NaN? I make sure it is not undefined.

```
double gradesMultiplied = ((quantityA * 4.00) + (quantityAMin * 3.70) + (quantityBPlu * 3.30) + (quantityB * 3.00) + (quantityBMin * 2.70) + (quantityCPlu * 2.30) + (quantityC * 2.00) + (quantityCMin * 1.70) + (quantityDPlu * 1.30) + quantityD + (quantityDMin * 0.70));
double gradesAdded = (quantityA + quantityAMin + quantityBPlu + quantityB + quantityBMin + quantityCPlu + quantityC + quantityCMin + quantityDPlu + quantityD + quantityDMin + quantityF);
double calcGPA = gradesMultiplied / gradesAdded;
```

Comment: I suspect that both `gradesMultiplied` and `gradesAdded` are zero.

Comment: Or one of the many quantities you are adding is `NaN` already.

Comment: This would be much easier if you used an array instead of these `quantityXXX` variables.

Comment: try printing out the values of gradesMultiplied and gradesAdded before you try the division (use System.out.println(gradesMultiplied)  or use a debugger and see what the values are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NaN is Not a Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean), try explicitly converting all values to numbers in the beginning.

Also looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618081/546411) is it possible you are dividing zero by zero?

> "NaN" stands for "not a number". "Nan" is produced if a floating point operation has some input parameters that cause the operation to produce some undefined result. For example, 0.0 divided by 0.0 is arithmetically undefined. Taking the square root of a negative number is also undefined.

Comment: that was what i was pointing out just didnt type it right, I updated though. Thanks & cheers

Comment: I know i am not dividing by zero because i make sure gradesAdded is not a zero

Comment: @tchristofferson then odds are there is a NaN value in that chain

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it everybody. I had to put the first 2 lines in my methods that add the quantity when pushing button.