# i have NaN error in my project EDITED

Tags: java, c

1. full code

   ```
     the full code of the neuron. am trying to code a radial basis                    neuron network but i can figure out where and getting an NaN error
   ```

   import java.util.ArrayList;
       import java.util.List;
       import java.util.Random;

   ```
   public class Neurons {

       static Random rand =new Random();
       instance variables


       private float m_neuronOutput;
       private float alpha=0.4f;
       private  float  m_gradient;
       private int neuronIndex;
       public  float eta;
       public float sigma=22.5f;
       public List<Connection> neuronWeights= new ArrayList<Connection>();
       //public List<Center> neuronCenter= new ArrayList<Center>();
       NetWork net=new NetWork();
       public Neurons(){
           //  sigma=22.5f;
           eta=0.5f;

       }
       //neuron constructor
       public Neurons(int outputNum, int m_neuronIndex){
           neuronIndex=m_neuronIndex;

           add connection weights
           for (int connect = 0; connect < outputNum; connect++) {
               neuronWeights.add(new Connection());


           }


       }

       public  void SetOutputValue(float value){
           m_neuronOutput = value;

       }
       public float GetOutputValue(){
           return m_neuronOutput;
       }
       ## feed the layer with the input ##
   ```
2. feed the layers

   ```
       public void FeedForward(Layer previousLayer, int n){
           float sum = 0;
           //weightsum the inputs of the last layer, including bias
           //System.out.println(n);
           m_neuronOutput= previousLayer.neuron.get(n).GetOutputValue () ;
           //System.out.println(m_neuronOutput);
       }
   ```
3. set the value of the hidden layer

   ```
       public void FeedHidden(Layer previousLayer, int j ){

           //      for(int i=0;i<center.length;i++)
           //          System.out.println(center[i]);
           float distance= 0;
           //System.out.println(n+" "+hiddenLayer.neuron.get(n).neuronCenter.get(n).center);
           //weightsum the inputs of the last layer, including bias
           for (int n = 0; n <previousLayer.neuron.size(); n++) {
               distance += (float) Math.pow(previousLayer.neuron.get(n).GetOutputValue ()-previousLayer.neuronCenter.get(j).center,2);
               //System.out.println(previousLayer.neuronCenter.get(j).center);
           }

        ## where am calling phi(Gaussian function) ##                  m_neuronOutput =  phi (distance);
           //System.out.println(m_neuronOutput);
       }
           private float phi( float distance){

           //System.out.println(sigma);
           return (float) Math.exp(- distance/(2*Math.pow(sigma, 2)));
       }
   ```
4. calculate output

   ```
       public void setOutput(Layer hidden){
           float output=0;
           for(int i=0;i<hidden.neuron.size();i++){
               output+=hidden.neuron.get(i).GetOutputValue()*hidden.neuron.get(i).neuronWeights.get(neuronIndex).weight;
               // System.out.println(hidden.neuron.get(i).GetOutputValue());
               // System.out.println(hidden.neuron.get(i).neuronWeights.get(neuronIndex).weight);
           }
           m_neuronOutput=output;
           //System.out.println(hidden.neuron.get(i).neuronWeights.get(neuronIndex).weight);

       }
   ```
5. gradient at the output layer

   ```
       public void CalcOutputGradients( float targetValue,float output){
           // System.out.println(output);
           float delta = targetValue -output;


           m_gradient = delta;
           //System.out.println( output);

       }   

       public void UpdateInputWeights(Layer previousLayer,float eta){
           //System.out.println(phi);
           the weights to be updated are in the connection container
           in the neurons in the preceding layer
           int numNeuronas = previousLayer.neuron.size();
           for (int n = 0; n < numNeuronas; n++) {//for every previous layer neuron
               Neurons neu = previousLayer.neuron.get(n);//getting the previous layer neuron
               //System.out.println(neu.neuronCenter.get(neuronIndex).center );
               float phi=previousLayer.neuron.get(n).GetOutputValue ();
               //double oldDeltaW = neu.neuronWeights.get(neuronIndex).deltaweight;
               double deltaWeight=
                       //Individual input magnified by the gradient and trainrate
                       eta *phi*m_gradient;
               also add momentum = a fraction of the previos delta weight
               +oldDeltaW;
               neu.neuronWeights.get(neuronIndex).deltaweight = deltaWeight;
               neu.neuronWeights.get(neuronIndex).weight+= deltaWeight;

               //System.out.println(m_gradient +" delta");

           }
       }
   ## my method to update the center but yet to call it in my network  work class ##
       public void updateCenter( Layer previousLayer,float[] input, float eta){
           int numNeuronas = previousLayer.neuron.size();

           for (int n = 0; n < numNeuronas-1; n++) {//for every previous layer neuron
               Neurons neu = previousLayer.neuron.get(n);//getting the previous layer neuro
               Center neu1 = previousLayer.neuronCenter.get(n);
               float phi=previousLayer.neuron.get(n).GetOutputValue ();
               double oldcenter = neu1.center;

               double weight= neu.neuronWeights.get(neuronIndex).weight;
               double deltaC=
                       //Individual input magnified by the gradient and trainrate
                       eta *phi*((m_gradient*weight)/Math.pow(sigma, 2))*(input[n]-oldcenter);
               //also add momentum = a fraction of the previos delta weight
               //+oldcenter;


               neu1.center+= deltaC;

               //System.out.println(gredient+" delta");

           }



       }
   ```

   ### update sigma

   ```
       public void updateSigma(Layer previousLayer, float[] center, float[] input, float eta){
           float distance= 0;
           //weightsum the inputs of the last layer, including bias
           for (int n = 0; n < center.length; n++) {
               distance+= Math.pow(previousLayer.neuron.get(n).GetOutputValue () -center[n],2);
               //System.out.println(distance);
           }
           float phi=(float) phi(distance);
           float sigma1=0;
           for(int i=0;i<center.length;i++){
               double w =previousLayer.neuron.get(i).neuronWeights.get(neuronIndex).weight;
               sigma1=(float) (sigma+(eta*((m_gradient*w)/Math.pow(sigma, 3))*phi*Math.pow(input[i]-center[i],2)));
           }
           sigma=sigma1;
       }
       get the current learning rate
       public  float updateLearningRate(float epoch){  
           //search the converge algorithm

           return (float) (eta/((epoch)/500));

       }

       set the learning rate
       public  void  setLearningRate(float rate){  

           eta=rate;

       }

       update the learining rate
       public  float getLearningRate(){
           return eta;

       }




   }
   ```

   looking for word to your help. Thanks

Comment: please add the full stacktrace

Comment: Can't remember if this return `NaN` or `Can't divide by 0` but this could be the reason `(float) Math.exp(- distance/(2*Math.pow(sigma, 2)));`might be equals to 0/0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, what does NaN mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean)

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see which line produced the NaN and what the inputs where which created it.

Comment: It is not possible to explain what is going on here.  You are calling methods that are not shown, and (apparently) some of the methods that are shown are not called; e.g. `phi(...)`

Comment: Please update your code to show us the **relevant** portions. As it is right now, the code that is present wouldn't show the problematic behaviour (i.e. it doesn't call `phi(float distance)` which is the only place a `NaN` could occur)

Comment: eta *phi*m_gradient;

Comment: neu.neuronWeights.get(neuronIndex).weight+= deltaWeight  //this the line of code that is causing the problem but i can't figure out why

Answer (score 2):

```
return (float) Math.exp(- distance/(2*Math.pow(sigma, 2)));
```

in the above line, when `sigma` and `distance` are `0`, you execute `Math.exp(-0/0)` which is `NaN`.

`NaN` stands for `Not a Number` which occurs e.g. when you divide by 0 or take a square root of a negative number.

`NaN` is defined by *IEE 754* and stands for a double which isn't actually numeric value.

*And as a side remark, as I believe you will read, please always add the stacktrace to the question. Always add all important information about the problem.*

Comment: @StephenC I made an experiment and Math.exp(0/0) is NaN

Comment: @StephenC of course you can. You were right. At the moment I believe there is a good answer.

Comment: Yes, if is was called with distance zero and sigma zero, that would lead to a NaN.  (You got that right now).  However, the `phi` method is not even called in the code that the OP showed us!  So, on the face of it, there is no evidence that the NaN comes from the `phi` call at all.

Comment: the distance that am passing to method phi() is never 0 and for testing purpose and i set assign sigma to a constant value. so there is no possibility of 0/0 in method phi()