# JTextField converted to Double returning NaN

Tags: java, string, double, jtextfield, nan

i'm new here and also coding, i'm doing my course conclusion project and having difficulties to find where is the error.
Basically my code are:

```
kilograms = Double.parseDouble(kgTextField.getText());
meters = Double.parseDouble(metersTextField.getText());
pounds = Double.parseDouble(poundsTextField.getText());
inches = Double.parseDouble(inchesTextField.getText());
result = (kilograms) / (meters * meters);    
resultTextField.setText(String.format("%,.2f", result ));
```

The result is giving me a NaN value and i'm not finding where is the error.
I'm doing the conversion from string to double in the variables but still doesn't work. Can someone give me a light?

Cheers

Comment: need more code to find error

Comment: What did you pit in the text fields? And why is your code referring to pounds and inches when that he nog used and irrelevant? Please post an [mcve] - follow the link to find out what it means.

Comment: `NaN` is procuded when both `kilograms` and `(meters * meters)` equal `0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

> "NaN" stands for "not a number". It is produced if a floating point
>   operation has some input parameters that cause the operation to
>   produce some undefined result. For example, 0.0 divided by 0.0 is
>   arithmetically undefined. Taking the square root of a negative number
>   is also undefined.

quote taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean)

In your case, you have to check if the values obtained from the text fields are valid and treat invalid values accordingly.

ex. meters must be != 0

the code chunk below is taken from java.lang.Double and illustrates the possible results of dividing a double value by 0.0

```
 /**
 * A constant holding the positive infinity of type
 * {@code double}. It is equal to the value returned by
 * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff0000000000000L)}.
 */
public static final double POSITIVE_INFINITY = 1.0 / 0.0;

/**
 * A constant holding the negative infinity of type
 * {@code double}. It is equal to the value returned by
 * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0xfff0000000000000L)}.
 */
public static final double NEGATIVE_INFINITY = -1.0 / 0.0;

/**
 * A constant holding a Not-a-Number (NaN) value of type
 * {@code double}. It is equivalent to the value returned by
 * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L)}.
 */
public static final double NaN = 0.0d / 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

thx for your answers and i'm sorry for didn't had posted cod enough to identify the error, as i told i'm newbie yet hehehe

My error was that i insert the variables in another section, so the system was identifying my variables as "0.00" so return to me a NaN error.

It's fixed now.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> JTextField converted to Double returning NaN

Cast conversions are well-defined. You don't have to guess, just check the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html). (int,float & long) to double is a widening conversion.

> private double result;

```
  private double result;
    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    double kilograms = 0.0;
    double meters = 0.0;
    if (meters > 0) {
        result = (kilograms) / (meters * meters);
    } else {
        result = 0.0; //As you wish to store except NaN
    }
    jTextField1.setText("" + result);
    }
```

Conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, may result in loss of precision-that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode.

Cheers