# What does System.out.format("height is %3.1f percent greater than length\n", percentage); do in Java?

Tags: java, format, system.out

I have a variable called -- `double percentage` and I wanted to print it using

```
System.out.format("height is %3.1f percent of the length\n",percentage);
```

When I don't enter a value for the height it returns this `NaN` percent of the length. What does `System.out.format()` do exactly?

And what does `NaN` mean and why does it get displayed in the output message?

Comment: [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html); `NaN` means **Not a Number**.

Comment: Are you dividing by zero?

Answer (score 0):

It's not what `format` is doing - a `float` or `double` can have a distinguishable value known as `NaN`, for "not a number", for a mathematically invalid result.

If you try and format such a NaN value, then `format` will appropriately represent it as the string "NaN.

Presumably you have some calculation resulting in a NaN value. Maybe there's an arithmetic operand that's uninitialized, though I'd have expected that to result in a "not initialized" compile-time error.  Without that code, I can only guess *how* you're getting the NaN result.

Related SO question: [what does NaN mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean) 
- this is not really a duplicate, because of the 'format' angle in the present question.

[IEEE 754 info on NaN and infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Exception_handling) from Wikipedia.

A simple example:

```
class Nan {
    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 0, b = 0;
        double c = a / b;
        System.out.format("%f / %f = %f \n", a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
$ java Nan
0.000000 / 0.000000 = NaN
```