# Lambda for checking NaN value while passing variable in a function

Tags: java, nan

Is there any lambda expression through which I can replace the `NaN` value to `0` or `-1` while passing it to a function?

I know I can put a check for `NaN` like this:

```java
if (Double.isNaN(variable_name))
{
        // make it 0 or -1
}
```

But I want to do it using lambda expression like

```java
function_to_called("variable_string", variable_double); // have a check if variable double is NaN
```

Comment: You mean something like `n -> Double.isNaN(n) ? -1 : n`?

Comment: @tobias_k, that's exactly what I needed. I forgot about `Ternary operators`. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a ternary `... ? ... : ...` instead of your `if` check and make that a `lambda`:

```
Function<Double, Double> deNan = n -> Double.isNaN(n) ? -1 : n;
```

However, while this is nice and short, this way you will have to call `apply` on the `Function` instead of being able to call the function directly, i.e. you'd have to do `function_to_called("variable_string", deNan.apply(variable_double));`. So instead, you might just define it as a regular method instead of a lambda so you can use it as `deNan(variable_double)`.

Also, as already noted, replacing `NaN` with a "special" (or not-so-special) value like `0` or `-1` might actually not be such a good idea. Instead, it might be better to filter out `NaN` values entirely, or to handle them "properly", whatever that entails in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in method because in [Floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) `NaN` constant represents something which is [undefined or unrepresentable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). This is not the same as specific value like 0 or -1. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2618059/1602555) which explains what `NaN` is.

You should handle it yourself by writing the right logic in your own method, like you already did with the `if` statement.